# Hyper-V VM wont start with more the 22gb RAM and produces Error Code 0x80070070

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v, memory, windows-server-2022

Currently got a server with 512GB of RAM and want to allocate 22GB of RAM to VM's on Hyper-V, currently have three machines, two with 22GB and one with 24GB RAM and are working fine but the fourth VM I am trying to created won't allow for 22GB of RAM and produces an error code 0x80070070 and says there is not enough space on the disk even though there is 3.5TB+ of disk space and 413GB of physical RAM space.

If I lower the RAM to 21.9GB, the machine starts fine, it seems the cut off point is 22GB exactly for the machine not to start.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: How are you doing for disk-space?

Comment: Not enough disc space. Unless the space WHERE IT ALLOCATES THE SAVE FILE has enough space, the space you quote is irrelevant - check the location it puts the VM data to.

Comment: The VHD is stored on a separate disk drive with 3.5TB of storage, currently 3.24TB available, the C Drive is completely full with 90MB remaining, could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

C Drive where Hyper-V is installed must have free space. I freed up around 60gb and VM's are working with 22GB RAM